# Python чем отличается Unicode от двоичного кода?

Tags: кодировка, unicode, ascii

Есть встроенные функции:

```
ord(), chr()
```

и есть

```
hex(), bin(), ....
```

Одни принимают только символы латиницы а другие - цифры. Я не понимаю различие `Unicode` от обычного двоичного или шестнадцатеричного кода.

Comment: В документации по питону есть раздел Unicode Howto. Там очень хорошо написано (тут [русский перевод](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/howto/unicode.html#id2)), не поленитесь прочитайте хотя бы главы Определения и Кодировки, они короткие, а сразу ставят все на свои места.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного всё в одну кучу, ну да ладно.

`Unicode` - это кодировка *символов* и строк, состоящих из символов. Кодировок существует много всяких, обычно родная кодировка `Python3` - это `UTF-8`, одна из разновидностей `Unicode`. Хотя под `Windows` это может быть и кодировка `cp1251`.

`ord()` - это функция, которая преобразует символ в его числовой код (место символа в таблице кодировки). Можно также сказать, что это внутреннее компьютерное представление символа.

`chr()` - это функция, обратная функции `ord()`, она преобразует число в соответствующий этому числу символ.

`hex()` - это функция, которая преобразует число в строку, соответствующую представлению этого числа в *шестнадцатеричной системе*. В каких-то случаях бывает полезно увидеть числа в таком представлении.

`bin()` - функция, преобразующая число в строку, соответствующую представлению этого числа в *двоичной системе*.

Важно понимать, что две последние функции дают строки, соответствующие представлению числа в определённой системе, но вообще вы можете работать с числами опираясь на любую из систем в их исходном виде, для этого не нужно с ними ничего делать.

Например:

`print(1000 - 10) # 90` - вычитаем число 10 в десятичной системе
`print(f'{0b100 | 0b11:b}') # 0b111` - выставляем два младших бита числа, для удобства я использовал двоичное представление чисел, но это не строки (до печати), точно так же можно было бы использовать десятичное представление чисел

В общем, тут главное понять разницу между внутренним представлением чисел и строк и их представлением при выводе на печать.

Comment: Я понимаю что делают функции, но не вижу различий и не понимаю целей применения им. Есть определение "кодировка" но зачем есть куча разных, в виде Unicode и двоичной системы. НО двоичная система это же те самые 0101. Почему нельзя кодировать информацию на двоичной системе или восьмеричной - шестнадцатеричной? для чего Unicode, ASCII, UTF-8, UTF16 если есть двоичная система, как это всё связано?

Comment: @Alegro юникод сам по себе просто задаёт соответствие символов определённым числам (обычным человеческим числам, не компьютерным). А уже кодировки вроде UTF-8 и UTF-16 определяют, как записать эти числа в пригодном для компьютера виде. Почему куча разных - просто исторически сложилось.